# How to stop a sticky element at the end of parent element

Tags: css, sticky

I have a layout with a content column and a sticky sidebar. Scrolling down the page I need to stop the sidebar at the end of the content column.

[image]

Here the HTML and CSS I'm using:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Content</div>
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar (sticky)</div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>


.content{
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

Also on https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awNorj

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: You can't put anything on a web page without inserting it into the DOM so I don't understand your question but you are required to post your markup here, not codepen, where it can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with DOM? Maybe a screenshot will help. I don't see the "goes under the endline of the right column" effect you mention.

Comment: Guys, this is the behaviour he wants http://i.imgur.com/NTVo5ro.png but instead he gets this http://i.imgur.com/M80qLWU.png

Comment: @RickyDam Ah, that clear it up. Thanks.

Comment: @RickyDam that's it! Thanks. Anyway I just updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: hi @MrLister could you help? let me know if question isn't clear yet

Answer (score 2):

Your initial problem is that css tricks work fine for top elements but not for bottom elements. Because tricks rely on the top-left corner position. To do so with the bottom-left corner, you'd need to know the height of your sidebar.

**With sticky top element**, you could just:

- put your sidebar div first
- then your content div
- finally set your sidebar `float:left` so the container adjusts its height to the content

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1owyqtcn/1/

**With sticky bottom element**, the `float:left` trick does not work: it will get your sidebar overflow the container at the bottom.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/d1byrhp6/4/

---

### If you don't know the height of your sidebar.

---

An approach can be to use the **negative margin-left trick**: you put the sidebar div into the content div and display it outside. Both sidebar and content are now aligned. But the sidebar leaves blank space in the content.

```
.content{
  background: purple;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  width: 25%; /* Adjust: 25% of 80% of container is 20% of container */
  background: #ff6347;
  bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: -25%;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zg9g3134/

---

### If you know the height of your sidebar.

---

Another approach is to suppress the height with a **negative margin-top trick**, instead of a `float: left`.

```
.content{
  background: purple;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin-top: -200px;
  position: sticky;
  width: 20%;
  background: #ff6347;
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rLs8dLba/2/